# MySQL server are very slow

Tags: php, mysql, magento, nginx, varnish

Please help me with the issue.
My main problem is that mysql is very slow. When I try to create products in my CMS, it takes much time. Example: creating product takes 4 min, deleting product - 12 min.

I use CMS `Magento 2.2 CE` (community edition). Also there are **145 000** products there. Before we added products all was fine. Creating product took about 5 sec, deleting product was about 5-10 sec.

Here is my system:
​​​​​​

```
Ubuntu 14 x64, Linux kernel 3.13, 16 cpu, SSD, 48 GB RAM
Magento 2.2 CE
Percona MySQL server 5.6 - here is config - https://pastebin.com/TVu1Ed7c
Varnish server 4.1
PHP 7.0.22
Nginx 1.12
Redis Server 4.0.2
```

I try to run some profiling tests of magento and mysql:

```
Here is slow log results - https://pastebin.com/kbFw0F28
Here is example of mysql request that are very slow - https://pastebin.com/mi656h2h
```

When I run `mysqltuner.pl` it shows me that everything is OK.
Also if there are 60 real users on my site I see mysql process takes very high cpu load. As an example I have site on same CMS with 100 products and lower server< and it takes about 500 users and feels ok.

So help me please with this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Is your Magento 2 caches are enabled?

Comment: yes, enabled, varnish cache server

Comment: Please post your complete mysqltuner.pl report for analysis.